# UIActivityViewController issue iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I’m building an article reading app for iPad. I have integrated a social sharing functionality which means user can share articles on Facebook, and google mail.
I’m using `UIActivityViewController` for sharing.

There is a bar button item,when user click on that `UIActivityViewController` opens.I updated Xcode 6
When I run on simulator it runs fine But I run on real device(iPad) with iOS 7,the app get crash on clicking on bar button item.
 this is my code:

```
     - (IBAction)ysshareAction:(id)sender
       {

         NSURL *linkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_DetailModal1[4]];//article url
         NSMutableAttributedString *stringText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:_DetailModal1[0]];//_DetailModal1[0] contain article title////
        [stringText addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:linkURL range:NSMakeRange(0, stringText.length)];
        NSArray * itemsArray = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_DetailModal1[0]], [NSURL URLWithString:_DetailModal1[4]]];
        NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
        UIActivityViewController * AVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
        AVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = _webView;
        [self presentViewController:AVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        [AVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
        {

        if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
         ServiceMsg = @"Mail sent!";
     } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
         ServiceMsg = @"Article Shared!";
     } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
         ServiceMsg = @"Article Shared!";
     } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
         ServiceMsg = @"SMS sent!";
     } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]) {
         ServiceMsg = @"Added to Reading List";
     } else if([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]){
         ServiceMsg = @"Copied Link";
     }

     if ( done )
     {
         UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ServiceMsg message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [Alert show];

          }
       }];

    }
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Please mention crash logs in your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following line is the issue

```
AVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = _webView;
```

You will have to put iOS8 condition in order `popoverPresentationController` is introduced for iOS 8 and later so you can not use it with iOS 7

For checking for iOS8 you can define  a macro like found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on)

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

And use it in following way.

```
     NSURL *linkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_DetailModal1[4]];//article url
     NSMutableAttributedString *stringText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:_DetailModal1[0]];//_DetailModal1[0] contain article title////
    [stringText addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:linkURL range:NSMakeRange(0, stringText.length)];
    NSArray * itemsArray = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_DetailModal1[0]], [NSURL URLWithString:_DetailModal1[4]]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    UIActivityViewController * AVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

   if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){

        AVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = _webView;
   }
   [self presentViewController:AVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644054/uiactivityviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios8-ipads) for more info about what has changed for `UIActivityViewController` in iOS8

Comment: Thanks,could you please tell me what is isGreaterThaniOS8 here.                                                                  It shows an error:                                                  Use of undeclared identifier 'isGreaterThaniOS8'

Comment: Please check my edited answer , its a macro used to check if iOS version is greater than or equal to 8.0

Comment: Okey , it seems like there was some problem in macro , i have updated my answer.

Comment: The solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A lot might argue that checking for existence of the class explicitly is better than checking a hard coded version number.  UIPopoverPresentationController may be deprecated at some future point, or there might be a (future ?) device which does not support the class, like the iPhone never used to support UIPopoverController or UISplitViewController..

```
if (  NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverPresentationController")   ) {

AVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = _webView;


}
```

Comment: Agree with checking existence of a class, however, as of iOS 4.2, the recommended way of checking the existence of a class is to use the `NSObject class` method. In this case: `if ([UIPopoverPresentationController class]) {...}` The advantage is you get compiler type checking.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, You can use '?' instead checking OS version.
AVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = _webView