# Phone gap app crashes by tapping on select box on iOS 8

Tags: ios, cordova, crash, hybrid

I have created a phone gap app having two select boxes for date control and time control. On tapping more than once on any of these select boxes causes the app to crash. It gives the following error:

Error 1.** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:willRemoveScrollingLayer:withContentsLayer:forNode: delegate:  -[WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78f35320
Error 2. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController () should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.

I have read an answer ([UIActivityViewController crashing on iOS8 iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644054/uiactivityviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios8-ipads)) to solve this by native approach. Can anyone let me know how to fix it in the hybrid app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in my case (phonegap app with OnsenUI Framework) I faced the same problem and I figured out it happens due to -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; on multiple elements inside a wrapper. After removing the error was gone (at least in my case)