# UIActivityViewController bug in iOS 8

Tags: ipad, crash, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

Basically I was forced to check if the iOS version of the device is 8.0 and if it is an iPad to run the following code:

```
ActivityView.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = view;
ActivityView.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 50, 1, 1);
```

Otherwise the application crashes.

The problem now is it crashes in iPad Mini.

Comment: Simulator or actual?

Comment: actual. it crashes in the iPad Mini.

Comment: This topic to consist of all the answer that you will need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644054/uiactivityviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios8-ipads

Answer (score 0):

Basically, instead of checking for iOS 8 and iPad, I should check if the activityView responds to the selector popoverPresentationController.

```
[ActivityView respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) {
    ActivityView.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = view;
    ActivityView.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 50, 1, 1);
}
```