# Share button work in Iphone and not work in iPad - IOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

Share button works in iPhone but causes a crash in iPad.

Code :

```
let finaltext = "Text to share"

let objectsToShare = [finaltext]

let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank for Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing button works perfectly on iPhone but crash on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506081/sharing-button-works-perfectly-on-iphone-but-crash-on-ipad)

Comment: Sorry but can not help me : 
Error in Console  :
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Comment: The error you’ve written is non-fatal. Can you reproduce again and look for the error that actually caused the thread to crash?

Comment: Now it work but i have an other Error : 
[ShareSheet] connection invalidated

Answer (score 2):

Try to add sourceRect like this:

```
let finaltext = "Text to share"

let objectsToShare = [finaltext]

let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.maxY, width: 0, height: 0) //center bottom
present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```