# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to attach pdf to the mail but I am getting following error when i run in iOS 8. when i open activity

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged.
```

When i click on mail, i am getting

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController:> on <> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am using the following code to do so,

```
activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:PDFDataArray applicationActivities:nil];  
_popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
[_popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Not displaying a window.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `UIPopoverController` is not yet presented and still not a part of the window hierarchy.

The correct way to presnt `UIActivityViewController` is as follows:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:PDFDataArray applicationActivities:nil];

if ([activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) { 
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = myButton;
}    

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

No need of a `UIPopoverController`

Comment: I tried, but i am getting error as "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController: 0x7b823de0>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'"

Comment: I need to use popovercontroller for iPad. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644054/uiactivityviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios8-ipads

Comment: what is myButton i am not getting

Comment: myButton is any `UIView`,`UIButton`,`UIBarButtonItem` etc. object from where you want to show your popover for `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: @elavarasan: Let me know if it worked for u. Please do accept the answer.

Comment: I am getting error as UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController:>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs

Comment: Can you please add your complete code here. Unable to understand your problem.

Comment: I dismiss view before attachment ([self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimation:nil];) thats why i was getting "Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController:> on <> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" Now i am dismissing after sending an email. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your help