# UIDocumentMenuViewController crashes

Tags: ios, xcode7

It is strange the I have the same code in 2 applications. In one application `UIDocumentMenuViewController` opens up with no applications EVERY OTHER TIME, while there are no such issues in my other application. I looked into the logs. Every time my first application fails to show other document provider application.

Here's the error:

> Remote view controller error while displaying UIDocumentMenuViewController: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default.viewservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default.viewservice}

I tried to look up as much as I could tried to run everything with delay, in main queue, nothing works. Any help will be much appreciated

My original code to show `DocumentMenuViewController` is pretty straight forward, as one would expect:

```
let menu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeContent as String], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
menu.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As I debug my code, I noticed that this error shows up when I present the view controller and not when I create it.

Complete log

```
<_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x14e405430>.
2015-12-08 13:48:22.125 IBM Navigator[2930:919990] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2015-12-08 13:48:23.874 IBM Navigator[2930:920496] plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default interrupted
2015-12-08 13:48:23.875 IBM Navigator[2930:920486] plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated
2015-12-08 13:48:23.909 IBM Navigator[2930:919990] Remote view controller error while displaying UIDocumentMenuViewController: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default.viewservice" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default.viewservice}
2015-12-08 13:48:23.938 IBM Navigator[2930:919990] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
  Try this:
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14cf37930 UILabel:0x14e413280.width == UIView:0x14cfdaa30.width - 32>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14cfdd920 UIView:0x14cfdaa30.width == UIView:0x14cfb8210.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14e0e0c90 H:[UIView:0x14cfb8210(30)]>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14cf37930 UILabel:0x14e413280.width == UIView:0x14cfdaa30.width - 32>
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Any help/advice will be much appreciated

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Nope. Still out there

Comment: See https://openradar.appspot.com/27471372 and http://www.openradar.me/19385063 (and create copy of your own radar of the problem).

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25644145/3718570