# Sharing a subview as an image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to share a subview as an image. This question combines code from these two questions [conversion of a subview to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57206207/5217293) and [showing a `UIActivityController` in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533564/showing-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swiftui?answertab=votes#tab-top).

The view and minimal working example are below. I am trying to share `SubView`, here, the rectangle with the text as an image. The problem is that `self.uiimage` evaluates to `nil` whenever I press the button and causes the app to crash.

I ***know*** that an image can be created because I can add this line of code `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.uiimage!, nil, nil, nil)` in the `action` of the button and the image gets saved to the photos album.

My best guess is that the `ActivityViewController` is created when the entire UI is first rendered, at which point `self.uiimage` would be `nil`. I suppose I could make `uiimage` a binding property to `ActivityViewController`, but I would rather not do that since it would complicate creating the activityItems in the parent controller. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SubView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSharePresented: Bool = false
    @State private var rect: CGRect = .zero
    @State private var uiimage: UIImage? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        SubView()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .background(RectGetter(rect: $rect))
        
        Button(action: {
            self.uiimage = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.asImage(rect: self.rect)
            self.isSharePresented = true
        }) {
            Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSharePresented, onDismiss: {
            print("Dismiss")
        }, content: {
            ActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.uiimage!])
        })
    }
}

struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var activityItems: [Any]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {}
}

struct RectGetter: View {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            self.createView(proxy: proxy)
        }
    }

    func createView(proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rect = proxy.frame(in: .global)
        }

        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func asImage(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My best guess is that the ActivityViewController is created when the entire UI is first rendered

That's pretty much exactly the problem — SwiftUI sheets sometimes get pre-rendered, before your `uiimage` is set. Especially when you're working with optionals, [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) is the more reliable modifier.

The only requirement is to make the image conform to [`Identifiable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable). The easiest way to do this is probably to make a wrapper struct.

```
/// Conform to Identifiable.
struct ImageWrapper: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var image: UIImage
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rect: CGRect = .zero
    @State private var imageWrapper: ImageWrapper?
    
    var body: some View {
        SubView()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .background(RectGetter(rect: $rect))
        
        Button(action: {
            if let image = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.asImage(rect: self.rect) {
                self.imageWrapper = ImageWrapper(image: image)
            }
        }) {
            Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
        
        /// When `imageWrapper` is not nil, the sheet will be presented.
        .sheet(item: $imageWrapper) { imageWrapper in
            ActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageWrapper.image])
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image is not nil and the activity view controller is presented]